# Find key name in hash with only one key?

Tags: perl, hash

If I have a hash

```
my %h = (
    secret => 1;
);
```

and I know that is only is one key in the hash, but I don't know what it is called.

Do I then have to iterate through that hash

```
my $key;
foreach my $i (keys %h) {
    $key = $h{$i};
}
```

Or are there a better way to get the name of the key?

Comment: There is a [much easier solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42809337/2932052) than all answers given so far (including the accepted one). It's also shorter and easy to understand and remember.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A [list slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) should do it

```
(keys %h)[0]
```

`keys` returns a list, so just extract the first element of that list.

Comment: The only thing to watch out for with this method is the "looks like a function" problem. To avoid this you may need `((keys %h)[0])` for example `perl -E 'my %h = ( secret => 1); say (keys %h)[0];'` fails but `perl -E 'my %h = ( secret => 1); say((keys %h)[0]);'` works. The problem is that perl sees `say` and a `()` and so parses as `(say(keys %h))[0]`. So just be careful.

Comment: There are no arrays being returned or references being dereferenced. Fixed the terminology and added link to relevant docs.

Comment: Such an awesome answer. Saved my day :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 16):

```
my ($key) = keys %h;
```

As you're using list context on both sides of the assignment operator, the first item in the keys list gets assigned to $key.

Answer (score 11):

I do not believe it is necessary to use the `keys` function.

```
my ($key) = %h;
```

or

```
my $key = (%h)[0];
```

The hash inside the parens will be expanded to a list, then we can simply take the first element of that list, which is the key.

Comment: I agree that this will work. I think it is an example of the "too-clever-by-half" that gives Perl a bad name.

Comment: so is `my ($x) = %h` too clever by whole?

Answer (score 6):

```
my @keys = keys %h;
my $key = $keys[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

`[ keys %h ]->[0]` will also do the disambiguation [Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468327/joel) mentions in an earlier comment. This code smells like it will cause problems though. If there is really only a single key/value pair, there might be a better way to handle the data.

At the least, I'd check to be sure the expectation is never violated silently. E.g.‐

```
keys %h == 1 or die "ETOOMANYKEYS";
print [ keys %h ]->[0], $/;
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's **have a look** at

```
my ($key) = %h;
```

Hashes and arrays are not as different as they seem. They are both closely related to lists. Using lists is the way they are initialized normally, and `=>` is mostly an alias for `,` with the only difference that it treats its left operand quoted implicitly. Perl stops only if you forget the quotation of its right operand, so the following both lines will be accepted:

```
my %h = (a=>b=>c=>'d');
my @a = (a=>b=>c=>'d');
```

Well, did you ever try this?

```
my %h = ('key');
```

...or this:

```
my @a = ('value');
my %h = @a;
```

The hash above may look a bit strange, but it's just a key with the value `undef`.

Because it's most likely that you will ask how to access the single value, I suggest to use:

```
my ($key, $value) = %h;
```

...or even simpler:

```
my ($key) = %h;
```

That's what we started with.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $k = each %h;
```

However, you must remember to reset the iterator if you ever want to use it on the same hash again. Either another `each` will do it, or `keys` will, and if used in a scalar context, will avoid creating a list. So you can reset it with

```
scalar keys %h; 
# OR
each %h;          # <- gets the undef
my $k2 = each %h; # <- gets the first key
```

So you could do it like this:

```
my $k = ( scalar keys %h, each %h );
```

But assuming it like reading JSON messages and stuff where you just want to read what's in the hash once and throw it away, it is probably the most succinct. However, if you want the variable right away, it's probably easier to do this:

```
my ( $k, $v ) = each %$simple_JSON_structure;
```

Comment: keys in void context also works (and will be more efficient for a tied hash)

Comment: [But don't forget to reset the iterator using keys(%hash) afterwards or subsequent each will fail.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42809852/revisions)