# accessing "pair hash" references used for column specification

Tags: perl, hash, conventions

I'm building a small library that transforms log data into a CSV-like file that can be imported by spreadsheet software. For the output, I'm interested in an option to display human-friendly captions for the table columns if needed. This should be an option so that the tool can also be used with minimal effort. I came up with an array for column specification that contains plain scalars for keys or hash references with a pair of key and value. I'm accessing these via keys and values which looks a bit strange to me.

**Is there a simpler way to access key and value of a hash that contains just a pair?**

(I tried to simplify the code as much as possible.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

# some sample data
my @rows = (
    {x => 1, y => 2},
    {y => 5, z => 6},
    {x => 7, z => 9},
);

sub print_table {
    my @columns = @_; # columns of interest with optional header replacement
    my @keys; # for accessing the data values 
    my @captions; # for display on column headers
    for (@columns) {
        if (ref($_) eq 'HASH') {
            push @keys, keys %$_;
            push @captions, values %$_;
        } else {
            push @keys, $_;
            push @captions, $_;
        }
    }
    print join ("\t", @captions), "\n";
    for my $row (@rows) {
        print join ("\t", (map {$row->{$_} // ''} @keys)), "\n";
    }
}

print_table({x=>'u'}, 'y');
```

Comment: What's wrong with `keys` and `values`? Your code is already pretty simple.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot ...that's what I thought, but because [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) opens a list context, I found this **misleading** due to the intended singleton character of the arguments.

Comment: Nothing misleading about it, you can `push` single scalars just as well as multiple scalars: `push @foo, $bar`. I think you're over-thinking this.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it's about readability and minimal confusion ("self-documentation"), that's why I prefer using small hashs to two-element arrays on caller side of `print_table`. Maybe my last comment was itself a bit confusing, it's the plural forms `keys` and `values` that I considered misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need:

```
my ($k, $v) = %hash;
```

So

```
my ($k, $v) = %$_;
push @keys,     $k;
push @captions, $v;
```

or

```
push @keys,     ( %$_ )[0];
push @captions, ( %$_ )[1];
```

Comment: Great you bring this version (`my ($k, $v) = %hash;`). I meanwhile figured this out myself. And it looked so simple. It also teaches us a lesson about lists.

Comment: BTW: would you consider these "pair hashes" normal or does they typically indicate bad solutions. ...and can you suggest a more idiomatic solution for this kind of replacement?

Comment: It's unusual, but not necessarily bad. An array (e.g. `[ x => 'u' ]`) would be more convenient (`push @keys, $_->[0];`). Is it really that bad if the caller had to do `print_table(x=>'u', y=>'y')`?

Comment: Ah I see, well this [I already learned today](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42809337/2932052), but need to get used to it: `=>` isn't restricted to hashes :-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each`.

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

> When called on a hash in list context, returns a 2-element list
>   consisting of the key and value for the next element of a hash.

But don't forget to reset the iterator using `keys(%hash)` afterwards or subsequent `each` will fail.

```
my ($k, $v) = each(%$_);
keys(%$_);
```

Comment: @Wolf, No. Added caveat to answer.